# VSTO customization for Excel: event handler not working given multiple excel files are open

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

A document-level VSTO customization for Excel registers an event handler - `OnSheetChangeEventHanlder` -  for worksheet `Change` event.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public partial class ThisWorkbook
{
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Open += ThisWorkbookOpen;
    }

    private void ThisWorkbookOpen()
    {
        Excel.Sheets sheets = this.Sheets;
        Excel.Worksheet sheet = null;

        for (int i = 1, length = sheets.Count; i <= length; i++)
        {
            sheet = sheets[i];

            sheet.Change += OnSheetChangeEventHanlder;
        }   

        if (sheet != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
        if (sheets != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheets);
    }

    private void OnSheetChangeEventHanlder(Excel.Range Target)
    {
        // ..
    }
}
```

As expected, `OnSheetChangeEventHanlder` is called any time sheet data gets changed. However if we open two excel documents with the same customization and try editing sheet data in one of them, OnSheetChangeEventHanlder is not called. It looks confusing, the more for it being a document-level customization that makes me expect the customization instances should be isolated from each other.

So to summarize: why the presence of another open excel file prevents event registration or running custom event handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was not able to either fix this issue or find an explanation, and ended up with a workaround: removing and reattaching `OnSheetChangeEventHandler` in another event handler subscribed to `this.ActivateEvent`.